# How to get the visible width and height of a ThreeJS mesh object in pixel unit

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am facing the challenge of figuring out the visible view width and height of a ThreeJS mesh object in pixel units.

In the screenshot below you can see objects floating in 3D space, on mouse click I need to be able to figure out what view width and height they are occupying in pixels
[image]

As I am rather new to ThreeJS it is taking me rather long to find a solution, so I would welcome any kind of assistance.

The below function shows what kind of approaches I have been trying.

```
getObjectSizeInViewSpace(object){
      const size = new THREE.Vector3()
      const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object).getSize(size)
      size.project(this.camera)

      let halfWidth = window.innerWidth / 2;
      let halfHeight = window.innerHeight / 2;

      size.x = (size.x*halfWidth)
      size.y = (size.y*halfHeight)
      
      return new THREE.Vector2(size.x,size.y)
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [`Vector3.project()`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=vect#api/en/math/Vector3.project). This basically takes world-space (3D) coordinates, and uses the camera's viewport to convert into normalized device coordinates, which range from `[-1, 1]`. For example `x: -1` is the left side of the screen, and `x: 1` is the right side. So you'll have to take the 4 vectors (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right)` of your plane to calculate their pixel dimensions in your browser:

```
// Get 3D positions of top left corner (assuming they're not rotated)
vec3 topLeft = new Vector3(
    plane.position.x - planeWidth / 2, 
    plane.position.y - planeHeight / 2,
    plane.positon.z
);

// This converts x, y, z to the [-1, 1] range
topLeft.project(camera);

// This converts from [-1, 1] to [0, windowWidth]
const topLeftX = (1 + topLeft.x) / 2 * window.innerWidth;
const topLeftY = (1 - topLeft.y) / 2 * window.innerHeight;
```

Notice the `topLeftY` value is inverted, since `-y` in 3D space goes `+y` in pixel coordinates. Do this 4 times (once for each corner), and then you can subtract (right - left) to get the width, and the same for the height.

Comment: Thank you for the direction Marquizzo. 

I have extracted also the topRightXY, as seen below. 

const topRight = new THREE.Vector3(
          object.position.x + object.geometry.parameters.width / 2, 
          object.position.y + object.geometry.parameters.height / 2,
          object.position.z
      );

When I subtract topLeftX-topRightX, I am not getting the right pixel value...

Maybe, an important fact that I have left out in the description, is that if I click on an object it moves into view. (camera center).

Comment: @KreshnikHasanaj Then perform the calculations AFTER the object has moved to its final destination.

Comment: What is the opposite method of `Vector3.project()`? Instead of projecting from world space -> camera's device coords, go from cam device coords -> world space? Is this raycasting or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Nevermind! I just discovered `Vector3.unproject()`.